# How to plot multiple data usind add_axes without over writing existing

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, subplot, errorbar

I try to create a figure with zoomed inset graphs, where the data to the entire figure (all subplots and insets) is plotted at different positions of the code.

To mimic the plotting at different positions in the code, the minimum (NOT working) example loops over the plotting routine.

The subplots work, but their insets are overwritten each time. The inset axes are created using add_axes.

I have tried, not to create the subaxes (add_axes) each time, but only create them, if not already present by:

```
try:
    subax1
except NameError:
    subax1 = fig666.add_axes([0.5,0.71,0.35,0.16])
```

this also didn't help!

How can I fix the problem/ what is my conceptual misunderstanding?

Thanks for your help!!!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

x_data=numpy.array([0,    1,   1.85,   1.9,  1.95,   2, 2.1, 2.5,   5,  10, 25])
y_data=numpy.array([0,  2.5,    1.8,   0.5,   0.2,  11, 1.2, 0.5, 0.15, 10, 25])
y_data_err=y_data*0.1

number_of_runs=3
for iterator in range(number_of_runs):
    fig666=plt.figure(666,figsize=(22.0/2.54,18.0/2.54))
#############################
    # subplot
    ax = plt.subplot(3,1,1)
    #ax.plot(x_data,y_data+iterator*0.4,marker=None)              
    ax.errorbar(x_data,y_data+iterator*0.4,yerr=y_data_err)
    #plt.semilogy()
    plt.xlim(1.87,2.25)
    plt.ylim(0,3.7)   

    #####################
    #  zoomed inset to subplot ##
    subax1 = fig666.add_axes([0.5,0.71,0.35,0.16])
      #subax1.plot(x_data,y_data+iterator*0.2+0.1,marker=None)              
    subax1.errorbar(x_data,y_data+iterator*0.4,yerr=y_data_err)

    plt.xlim(1.87,2.25)
    plt.ylim(0,3.7)
```

Comment: I have slightly edited the code, to make it even clearer: there should be three errorbar plots in the subplot(3,1,1) and three errorbar plots in the inset graph. The inset graph however only shows a single one. Is it clear what I mean? Can anybody help? As far as I understand the documentation, the add_axes command should not overwrite the existing axes if the arguments are the same (which they are in above example). Is it a bug?? Citation from the matplotlib.org: "If the figure already has an axes with the same parameters, then it will simply make that axes current and return it..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be caused by the subplot command: as the inset plot/axes is entirely within the subplot, the inset axes/plot is removed as subplot is called again. Using add_axes to create the surrounding axes instead of subplot(3,1,1) fixes the issue:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

x_data=numpy.array([0,    1,   1.85,   1.9,  1.95,   2, 2.1, 2.5,   5,  10, 25])
y_data=numpy.array([0,  2.5,    1.8,   0.5,   0.2,  11, 1.2, 0.5, 0.15, 10, 25])
y_data_err=y_data*0.1



number_of_runs=3
index_lim=2

for iterator in range(number_of_runs):
    fig666=plt.figure(666,figsize=(22.0/2.54,18.0/2.54))
#############################
    # subplot
    #ax = plt.subplot(3,1,3)
    ax=fig666.add_axes([0.125,0.666,0.775,0.235])
    ax.plot(x_data,y_data+iterator*0.2,marker=None)              
    ax.errorbar(x_data,y_data+iterator*0.2,yerr=y_data_err)
    plt.semilogy()


    #####################
    #  zoomed inset to subplot ##
    subax1 = fig666.add_axes([0.5,0.71,0.35,0.16])
      #subax1.plot(x_data,y_data+iterator*0.2+0.1,marker=None)              
    subax1.errorbar(x_data,y_data+iterator*0.5,yerr=y_data_err)

    plt.xlim(1.87,2.25)
    plt.ylim(0,3.7)
plt.show()
ax = plt.subplot(3,1,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

x_data=numpy.array([0,    1,   1.85,   1.9,  1.95,   2, 2.1, 2.5,   5,  10, 25])
y_data=numpy.array([0,  2.5,    1.8,   0.5,   0.2,  11, 1.2, 0.5, 0.15, 10, 25])
y_data_err=y_data*0.1

number_of_runs=3
index_lim=2

for iterator in range(number_of_runs):
    fig666=plt.figure(666,figsize=(22.0/2.54,18.0/2.54))
#############################
    # subplot
    ax = plt.subplot(3,1,iterator+1)
    ax.plot(x_data,y_data+iterator*0.2,marker=None)              
    ax.errorbar(x_data,y_data+iterator*0.2,yerr=y_data_err)
    plt.semilogy()


    #####################
    #  zoomed inset to subplot ##
    [x0,y0], [x1, y1] = fig666.transFigure.inverted().transform(
        ax.transAxes.transform([[0.5, 0.2], [0.95, 0.9]]))
    subax1 = fig666.add_axes([x0, y0, x1-x0, y1-y0])
      #subax1.plot(x_data,y_data+iterator*0.2+0.1,marker=None)              
    subax1.errorbar(x_data,y_data+iterator*0.2,yerr=y_data_err)

    subax1.set_xlim(1.87,2.25)
    subax1.set_ylim(0,3.7)
```

the output:

[image]

to create the three large axes, you need change the third argument of `subplot()`:

```
ax = plt.subplot(3,1,iterator+1)
```

to create the zoom in axes, I use `transFigure` and `transAxes` to transform points in axes to points in figure.

```
[x0,y0], [x1, y1] = fig666.transFigure.inverted().transform(
        ax.transAxes.transform([[0.5, 0.2], [0.95, 0.9]]))
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.

In the end I want to have several subplots, but this is not my problem.

The code, I have posted was intended to create:
* a single figure
* with one subplot
*where the single subplot contains a single inset (created by add_axes)

*in each run a slightly displaced graph shall be plotted in the subplot as well as in the inset.

*it works well for the subplot, but not for the inset graph, where there always only remains the last plotted,

Comment: i.e.: in the inset there is only a single errorbar plot (blue line), while there should be three (as in the subplots). This is the problem: the insets are resetted in each loop

Comment: I have slightly edited the code, to make it even clearer: there should be three errorbar plots in the subplot(3,1,1) and three errorbar plots in the inset graph. The inset graph however only shows a single one. Is it clear what I mean? Can anybody help? As far as I understand the documentation, the add_axes command should not overwrite the existing axes if the arguments are the same (which they are in above example). Is it a bug??  Citation from the matplotlib.org:  "If the figure already has an axes with the same parameters, then it will simply make that axes current and return it..."